# Did this official picture of Rohan (Tenzin and Pema's son) appear in an episode?

Tags: episode-identification, the-legend-of-korra

During the last few episodes of *The Legend of Korra*, the show page on Nick.com (the network for the show) included family trees of the major characters. It has since been taken down, but was [preserved on this site](http://avatarthelastairbenderonline.com/family-tree-korra/). The Aang family tree is as follows:

[image: Aang family tree]

I recognize all of these pictures as coming from an episode of either *Avatar: The Last Airbender* or *The Legend of Korra*, except that of Rohan. The picture is much brighter than the others, and I only recall Rohan being a baby in *The Legend of Korra*, but he appears to be older in this picture.

Where did this picture of of Rohan come from? Was it an episode? A comic book? Or is it unique to this family tree?

Answer (score 4):

In this picture (at 1:08 minutes in season 4, episode 1), you can see Rohan at the oldest age that he ever appeared in the show.
This image is from the scene where Rohan was taken along by his parents to attend the grand reopening of Republic City's Central City Station.
As you can see, his image in the family tree you posted is probably just a fan copy of his face in this Picture
So that image is not taken from the show, rather copied (or maybe a better term is 'redrawn').

[image: oldest Rohan]

Comment: Which episode in the show is this from? Also, not sure if it's a "fan" copy if the family tree is the official one put out by Nickelodeon ;-)

Comment: 1:08 minutes in season 4, episode 1.  And if it was not made by a fan, I guess they could not use this 'smudged' face in the family tree so they just redrew it for that picture :)

Comment: @Thunderforge I would appreciate it if you accepted my answer. thanks :]